# background Geolocation plugin is not working for the second time of initialization of app in phonegap (IOS)?

Tags: cordova, geolocation, phonegap-plugins

I am using org.transistorsoft.cordova.background-geolocation plugin and when I open the app for the first time it is working with no error but when I close it and initialize it for the second time it gives me an error (**code:2 message:The operation couldn't be completed (KCLErrorDomain error 0)**).

```
$scope.$on('deviceReady', function(event, args) { 
  $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition({maximumAge: 7000,timeout: 10, enableHighAccuracy: true}).then(onSuccess, OnError);     
  var onSuccess = function(position) {
    alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
    'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
    'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
    'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
    'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
    'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
    'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
    'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
  }
  var OnError = function(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
    'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
  }
});
```

**Note: I have also set the default location option in Xcode.**